# Whats a good way to make the antagonists goal morally wrong, in the context of my story?

Tags: super-powers, secret-society, supernatural

So this one might be a bit difficult, but still, here goes.

In this world, in ancient times, humans used to hunt this very specific type of creature. These creatures where the only source of a certain, very addicting, exotic compound that triggers humans to "transform" into something of a demi-god. Think: enhanced strength, perception, intellect and even the ability to make small changes to their body at will. The more of this exotic compound they consumed the greater these effect. With these powers they became the apex creatures of their land and soon they started to build civilizations with kingdoms and castles. Their civilization was comparable to Victorian era England, with a lot more cultural influence from the creature hunting of course.

However, after a while the creatures which they hunted for this compound became extinct from the constant hunting of them. Without a source of this compound humans quickly started to regress to their original state. Madness swept across the human population because of the effects that came with essentially being forced to stop using an incredibly addictive drug. And because of a series of events set in motion by this mass "cold turkey" the human civilization quickly crumbled to something much more medieval. Only a select few of these "demi-humans" managed to stockpile some of this compound, which they now use to rule over the normal/regressed humans as royalty. However, this stock is of course finite. Which is why they're trying to create an artificial version of this compound. Which brings me to my question:

These royals, are the "villains" of the story. I would like to have the main conflict revolve around their quest to create this compound. The process of creating this miracle substance should be something which is very morally questionable/wrong in order to create the catalyst for the "heroes" to have to take action. It should also be at least somewhat scientific-ish. However i can't think of anything that would fit that bill. Which is what i hope you could help me with.

Also, bonus points if it gives a reason for some of these last demi-gods to roam the land. (an encounter between the protagonist and one of these roaming demi-gods is what sets the story into motion).

Thanks in advance and good luck!

Comment: Does the process of creating the elixir have to intrinsically immoral? Would there be anything wrong with simply their manner of ruling being immoral?

Comment: Imho this question is better suited for Writing SE (but still would not be accepted there in its current form).

Answer (score 3):

### Won't somebody think of teh children?

There are only a few activities that pretty much all human cultures agree are 'beyond the pale', and most of them involve the abuse of children in some fashion.  If you want something your readers are going to accept as unquestionably evil, having your antagonists capture or breed children to utilise in some scientific-y plot to 'farm' them for this magical serum, is a pretty safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

**The Right to Self Rule**

You don't even need something amoral about the process for the humans to act. In a world of Demi-Gods and humans, which one would be in charge? Demi-gods. People hate being ruled by someone from an out group.

And if there was excessive cruelty and death during the civilizations fall, you heroes could fear this happening again. At the best humans would become second class citizens under this system as Demi-Gods are more powerful. At worst, they would be little more than chattel.

**The Call to Action**

As for why there would be a roaming demi-god. Maybe he is testing a demi-god prototype drug on ill or dying people. He is offering them a choice: take this drug and if it works you become a demi-god, if not it will kill you. You're already dying. What do you have to lose?

MCs family member agrees to take the drug and it causes them to half transform and go mad. The MC has to kill the family member to save the town. Now MC knows about the plot and is committed to stopping it, because this demi-god is treating humans like lab-rats. To the MC this incident is another example of demi-gods treating humans like animals, and why demi-gods should never be allowed to rule.

Answer (score 1):

Between

> These creatures where the only source of a certain, very addicting, exotic compound that triggers humans to "transform" into something of a demi-god.

and

> These royals, are the "villains" of the story. I would like to have the main conflict revolve around their quest to create this compound. The process of creating this miracle substance should be something which is very morally questionable/wrong

So, are they likely to pull it off? On top of the other, completely sufficient answer (they extract the stuff from children and sad puppies), it is possible that they are toying with powers beyond their comprehension? I imagine their knockoff substance might have some side effects, sort of a Jekyll and Hyde scenario.

When regressing to madness, what comes first, the onset of madness or the loss of power? If madness comes first, you've got superpowered madmen. If the process of extracting the stuff is unreliable, and it has limited shelf-life, producing it seems to be inviting a situation in which people can't get their next hit. So each batch you send out has a high chance of producing some superpowered madmen.

Overall I think will have more trouble keeping your nobility from being cartoonishly evil!

Answer (score 0):

**Demigods themselves can be used as a source for the compound.**

It is a much inferior source -  a low quality imitation, and it relies on the fact that these demigods once used the real thing which continues to echo inside their bodies. They are captured and kept alive to provide the stuff, which is extracted from their bodies.  It is nasty.

This of course is why demihumans who are not part of the royal cadre are on the run.  They do not want to be rounded up and used in this way.  Sometimes one of the royal cadre winds up disappearing into the factory.

There is one demigod who is roaming around, fully powered up.  He has a companion, which is one of the creatures who provides this stuff; the last of its kind.  It provides the magic stuff willingly to its friend and they look out for each other.